# Option to configure .net version in DevExpress XAF not available

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, .net-6.0, xaf

I'm new to devexpress and wanted to create an XAF application in VS2022. During the creation configuration, I am unable to see the option to configure for a specific version of .net. [This is the creation screen available to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phZDq.png).

I have 6 installed on my system, yet the application is created in .net 5. I know I can change the version by simply editing the  for each project, but I was wondering if there was a UI directed way of doing so. Also, would there be a loss of some functionalities if I create the app in net5 and then change it to net6?

Answer (score 0):

For a new project, use the DevExpress Template Gallery Wizard and select the option on the first screen.
[image: Framework or Core]

For an existing framework project, in VS choose Extensions -> DevExpress->WinForms Controls -> Migrate the Current Project to .NET Core

[image: Migrate]